# Solar charging- battery overcharging due to resistance of path voltage drop

Tags: power-supply, power, batteries, solar-cell

I am trying to implement Solar charging for cells using LT3652, as mentioned by one of their modal circuit
[image]

The circuit works for multi-cell chemistry while charging till the VFB voltage reaches a certain level (using a resistive divider from the load line) since my circuit requires continuous power (irrespective of charging) the load line would always suffer voltage drop (from battery voltage) due to resistance of path. Since the charging is expected to be frequent, there is a possibility the battery will overcharge (since the circuit will try to maintain for example 8.4V on the load line which in turn makes the voltage of the battery around 8.4 + voltage drop due to path resistance) Is this a big issue or I am overthinking, since professionals at LT didn't though of this problem

Comment: The sense input has very high impedance, so all you need to do is to connect the line right near the load. There will not be a drop on the Sense signal.

Comment: Current through the resistor divider is negligible, about 0.00003 amps. Is that the load you are worried about? Or did you wire the system load to the BAT wire (don't do that)?

Comment: Yes, the load line directly goes to battery. Is this a problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you are concerned about.

Comment: since the load is directly connected to the battery the resistance of the path will affect the voltage right?